Excel copy and paste values with source formatting using OpenPyxl
Iam trying to copy the sheet from one workbook to another workbook and paste the whole content along with the source formatting. My source sheet has formulas and have to copy only values with source formatting to another workbook.
I was able to achieve the source formatting using openpyxl and when trying to copy value with option Data_only = True iam not seeing any values copied over. How should I copy values without formulas?
below is the code
# Load to New workbook
target_file = tgtfilepath+'\Finalextracts'+'\/'+'WB_TGT'+filedate+'.xlsx'
wb_target = openpyxl.load_workbook(target_file)

# Select the sheet where you want to paste data
target_sheet = wb_target["sheet_1"]

# Load the source workbook (this is where we get the data from)
source_file = tgtfilepath+'\Temp'+'\/'+'WB_src'+filedate+'_Temp.xlsx'

wb_source = openpyxl.load_workbook(source_file, data_only=True)  # data_only=True to get values, no formulas
source_sheet = wb_source.active  # Assuming data is in the active sheet of the source workbook

# Define the range to copy (example: A1 to D10)
source_range = source_sheet['A1:Z49']  # Adjust the range as needed
target_range_start_row = 1  # Adjust where you want to start pasting the data in target sheet

# Loop through the source range and copy only values to the target sheet
for row_index, row in enumerate(source_range, start=target_range_start_row):
    for col_index, cell in enumerate(row, start=1):
        target_cell = target_sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=col_index)

        # Copy only the value (no formula)
        target_cell.value = cell.value
        target_cell.font = copy(cell.font)
        target_cell.alignment = copy(cell.alignment)
        target_cell.border = copy(cell.border)
        target_cell.fill = copy(cell.fill)

# Save the modified workbook with values copied into the existing formatted sheet
wb_target.save(tgtfilepath+'\Finalextracts'+'\/'+'sheet_1'+filedate+'.xlsx')



It's pretty standard operation, and your code will do as your description states. Presumably if nothing is being copied it's your source_range that is not correct. Try debugging your code, for example check if you are writing any value to the target cells. For example add the line print(f"Cell Value written from Source {cell.coordinate} to Target {target_cell.coordinate}: '{cell.value}'") after # Copy only the value (no formula)  See what cells and values are being copied.
